# Why is every Sylow $p$-subgroup $p$-centric, i.e. why is $Z(P)$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $C_G(P)$, if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite grp. $G$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with order divisible by the prime number $p$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Why is then $Z(P)$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $C_G(P)$ ?

I tried:

$Z(P)$ is a $p$-group, since it is a subgroup of $P$.
Moreover, $N_{C_G(P)}(Z(P))=C_G(P)$. Hence, $Z(P)\unlhd C_G(P)$.
Furthermore, $P\cap C_G(P)=Z(G)$.

Now, let $Q$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $C_G(P)$ containing $Z(P)$.
$Z(P)\subseteq Q$ is clear, but why is $Q\subseteq Z(P)$ true?

Let $x\in Q\setminus Z(P)$. Since $x\in C_G(P)$, we have $rx=xr$ for all $r\in P$.

If $x\in P$, we are done, since then $x\in P\cap C_G(P)=Z(P)$ would follow.

Assume that $x\notin P$. Then, $P\subsetneq \langle P,x\rangle$. How can we derive a contradiction from here?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that $Z(P)=P\cap C_G(P)$. It follows that $|PC_G(P):P|=|C_G(P):Z(P)|$. Moreover, $PC_G(P)\leq G$ (can you see why?) Can you finish from there?

Comment: From your last step, x commutes with P, so $\langle P,x\rangle = \langle P \rangle \langle x \rangle$ is a normal product of p-groups, so is itself a p-group. Since P is maximal amongst p-subgroups, this means x is in P.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $C_G(P) \unlhd N_G(P)$ and $P$ is a (normal) Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Hence $Z(P)=C_G(P) \cap P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $C_G(P)$. (In general, if $N \unlhd G$, then $N \cap P \in Syl_p(N)$ if $P \in Syl_p(G)$.)

Comment: I was thinking that $C_G(P)$ is in general not normal in $G$, but I missed that - of course - it is normal in $N_G(P)$. Thank you.